# MongoDB groupby nested key and their value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this type of dataset in my MongoDB database :

```
{
"name": "Alex",
"domains": {
      "domain_1": 1,
      "domain_2": 1,
      "domain_3": 0
    }
},
{
"name": "Arthur",
"domains": {
      "domain_1": 1,
      "domain_2": 0,
      "domain_3": 3
    }
}
{
"name": "Paul",
"domains": {
      "domain_1": 0,
      "domain_2": 2,
      "domain_3": 3
    }
}
```

How can I get an output like this ? (group by domain's name and counting the number of level associated. I'm looking for a mongoDB query matching this output of something close:

```
{
    "domain_1": {
        "level_0": 1, #For my domain_1, I have 1 user with the level 0;
        "level_1": 2, #For my domain_1, I have 2 user with the level 1;
        "level_2": 0, #For my domain_1, I have 0 user with the level 2;
        "level_3": 0, #For my domain_1, I have 0 user with the level 3;
    },
    "domain_2": {
        "level_0": 1, # #For my domain_2, I have 1 user with the level 0;
        "level_1": 1, # ...
        "level_2": 1,
        "level_3": 0,
    },
    "domain_3": {
        "level_0": 1,
        "level_1": 0,
        "level_2": 0,
        "level_3": 2,
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Using *any* data as field names will only cause pain for future queries.  For example, the query could be simplified if `"domains"` was an array with elements like `{"domain": X, "level": Y}`.  Same for the output.  E.g., this would be easier, `{"domain": X, "levels": [{"level": Y, "count": Z}, ...]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

1. Use `$objectToArray` and `$unwind` to get simple documents
2. `$group` by `domain` and `level` to count
3. `$group` only by `domain` to create the wanted object format
4. `$mergeObjects` with the format to fill emptyentries
5. `$group` to format as one object according the requested result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {_id: 0, data: {$objectToArray: "$domains"}}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$group: {_id: {domain: "$data.k", level: "$data.v"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$group: { 
      _id: "$_id.domain", 
      data: {$push: {k: {$concat: ["level_", {$toString: "$_id.level"}]}, v: "$count"}}
  }},
  {$project: {
      k: "$_id",
      v: {$mergeObjects: [
          {
            "level_0": 0,
            "level_1": 0,
            "level_2": 0,
            "level_3": 0
          },
          {$arrayToObject: "$data"}
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$group: {_id: 0, data: {$push: {k: "$k", v: "$v"}}}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2mBrMIlm7Kj)

Comment: Beautiful  and amazing ! This is such a command !

Comment: A simple change can be like (this)[https://mongoplayground.net/p/R_xAOx9imOR]